# How do I trigger "git pull" from one computer, when another pushes to bitbucket?

Tags: linux, git, bitbucket

My webserver has a clone of my repo, hosted on BitBucket.

The issue is, every time I make a change to the repo, I need to ssh into the  webserver and git pull.

I'd like it so any time I push to BitBucket, it runs a script on the webserver which git-pulls the repo in question.

I have looked into web-hooks and it seems if I host my repo on the server I can use post-receive, that isn't exactly the best solution though.

Is it possible for the client to watch the repo and git pull (or run a script) when changes are made?

UPDATE: My current solution is a bash script that does a git pull every 30 seconds on loop forever

Comment: What's wrong with a cron job?

Comment: have you tried webhook?

Answer (score 0):

Making a pull request every thirty seconds sounds like it might waste a lot of the resources your server can be using for something else. I have three suggestions:

1. Perhaps you could use a websocket to notify the server that changes have been made. When it receives this message, the server could pull from the BitBucket repo.
2. If you don't have time to run the web socket, at least make sure your script is checking to see if updates are available before pulling. That should save your computer a little extra work.
3. Don't trigger git pull automatically. I would honestly recommend manually making a pull request if the git's changes might pose a risk to the application's performance. I don't know what the server you have is being used for, but if users are going to be interacting with it, then maybe this is the best suggestion.

Hope this helps